# Object design principle which describes interface symmetry

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, api, code-quality, api-design

Someone made a comment about some of my code which I thought was valuable, and I wanted to look up the design pattern to learn more, but I'm having a hard time identifying which design principle it relates to.

Essentially I had a Encoder/Decoder object. In one direction it would take a string and return an object with information about the string (lets say an object with a single integer). The reverse direction would take that integer and return a string.

The recommendation which was given to me was that if one direction takes a string and returns an object, the reverse should take that same object and return a string.

What (if any) design principle would this interface symmetry relate to?

Comment: There's no design pattern for this kind of symmetry.  It's just common sense.  When you're describing a lemon, you don't ascribe the taste to a pattern; you simply state that it is sour.  Design patterns are a vocabulary for well-known techniques that solve specific problems; they're not a way to stitch together a program or help you improve your taste.

Comment: If design pattern isn't the correct term, then perhaps design principal or design philosophy. Saying "It's just common sense" seems like a bit of a cop-out. You could say that about every design principle. Single responsibility principle is common sense too if you are experienced enough. Sure, in my simple example it's pretty obvious. It's meant to be. However, in real code it isn't quite so clear. I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: If you're doing things properly, you should already have a stated software requirement that says these two methods should "round-trip;" that is, given an initial data set, executing the Encoder method on the data set and then executing the Decoder method on the Encoder's result should produce the original data set (including preserving its type).

Comment: I am always skeptical when someone asks "which software pattern/principle/law does [some arbitrary code/method/operation] apply to," because the question always suggests cargo-cult thinking.  The universe of "laws and best practices that apply to software development" is neither comprehensive nor absolute; the only maxim that always applies is "does this principle best meet your specific requirements?"

Comment: So until we manage to create a comprehensive, absolute, unambiguous set of software design principles (it will never happen; software development is equal parts art and science), we'll still need software developers that know how to think for themselves, solve problems and make informed, non-dogmatic decisions.

Comment: Someone gave me feedback on my code which I thought was valuable, and I wanted to learn more. Thank you for your feedback about "round-trip" data flow.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on vocabulary; I put quotes around "round-trip" for a reason.  Round-tripping in software development is a technique for synchronizing software artifacts; it doesn't have much to do with your particular situation.  I'm using "round-trip" here in the metaphorical sense of taking an airline flight and returning to the same place from where you originated.

Comment: One could call this a "Reversible" interface/design.

Comment: I don't agree that the advice is even a good idea without caveats (likely so many / so vague as to render the advice meaningless). If I have a decoder that takes in a string and produces a data type representing either the decoded value or an error message (something like `Either Error A` in Haskell), that doesn't at all mean that the encoder should take in that data type. I suspect the OP's problem had some aspect of this and that the advice was actually bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This design corresponds to the mathematical concept of the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function):

If two functions f and g are such as:

```
    f: S -> D  (f takes elements in set S and maps them to elements in set D) 

    g: D -> S  (g takes elements in set D and maps them to elements in set S) 

    and for any x in S,  g(f(x)) = x
```

then g is said to be the inverse function of f.

If you transpose this to your problem:

```
   encode:   object -> string 
   decode: string -> object
   decode(encode(text)) = text
```

and nobody would challenge that `decode()` is the inverse of `encode()`

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to think of this term myself, but kept coming up with "distributive," "commutative" and  "associative" (none of which are correct).

Comment: Good answer.  Should be noted that writing a Unit Test of the form `assertEquals(decode(encode(text)), text)`, which seems logical (in most cases) to me, is surprisingly controversial.  YMMV

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's because of the lord of the [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) ;-)  also an inverse but packaged together with the undesired associative, distributive, and commutative aspects

Comment: @user949300  `assertEquals( encode(decode(crypt)), crypt)` would make me much more uncomfortable because there's no guaranty that encode is a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

Comment: "Inverse" is also incorrect. You could say "post-inverse" or (ambiguously) "left inverse", but inverse would mean `g(f(x))=x` *and* `f(g(y))=y`. You could call `f` a section and `g` a retract though. A more programmer-friendly name may be an "embed-project pair" with `f` and embedding and `g` a projection.

Comment: Taking this mathematical view also suggests that *every* object can be "encoded" into a `string`. If `object` here stands for the particular data type then that's potentially fine. If `object` here stands for something like Java's `Object`, then that's very clearly not the case. The question makes it sound that the "object" returned has more information than just the decoded value but maybe the idea is that only a subset of the decoded value (the "integer") is necessary to uniquely re-encode it.

Comment: Is implementing interfaces as inverse functions considered a software best practice? With `assertEquals(decode(encode(text)), text)` being controversial and other comments, I'm honestly torn between "It's common sense to do this" and "You can do this, but it's really not important"

Comment: @nanotek i would not overgeneralize by calling it a best practice.  But in your specific case of having two functions, one being the inverse of the other, it is certainly a very sound and consistent design practice.  Don't you expect that decode(encode(object)) is the same as object ? The controversy is only about the meaning of equal (i.e. in java two objects are only equal if they are the same instance, not if they are clones, i.e. different objects with same values in each member)